# Just changed from Unity to KDE, now my sidebar is gone

Tags: 14.04, unity, kde

I'm new to Linux, installed Ubuntu yesterday and today I've changed from Unity to KDE, but when I restarted the system, the sidebar disappeared.
I can only see my desktop and the things in it.

Ubuntu version: 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean the toolbar on the left side of Unity is not there? Isn't that how a regular desktop like KDE is supposed to look?

You should be able to add or move a bar to the left side if you prefer, or use a program like docky or cairo-dock to add a fancy unity-like (mac-like) dock / menu to whichever side you wish. (I liked docky, but really prefer a regular old-fashioned desktop with a "programs" menu without a "dock")

---

FYI, here's a decent looking How To Install Programs question: [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

And a nice quick overview of different desktops, with some install info: [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

An excellent way to try out new desktops is to use the live iso's, either on a cd/dvd/usb (cd-rw or dvd-rw to just try briefly), or boot them in VirtualBox or another VM (little slower than "for real"). There's iso's for Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu, and the Mint iso's use Cinnamon (like customized gnome 3) or mate (gnome 2 fork?), or Mint xfce & others

Comment: so... how is the correct way to use KDE?

Comment: KDE should look & act a lot like windows 7, vista, xp... a "start menu" with programs to run & settings & things, open windows/running programs listed in a windows-area of a bottom or top bar, etc. Plus KDE has some extra widgets to display more info or stats, maybe on the desktop or a bar, I'm not very familiar with them.

Comment: Is there a bar (on top or bottom or both) with programs and things like a clock, open windows, etc? If not then maybe not everything has started up or been configured correctly

Comment: No, that's the point, there's nothing, only the desktop.

Comment: I think if I install another environment the problem will be solved, any suggestions? I'm looking for a customizable one

Comment: Not having any bars anywhere is a problem, something didn't configure or start correctly. Maybe it got installed strangely, an `apt-get` purge and install again may help? I found a few metapackages that should install ALL the kde stuff (programs too), like `kubuntu-desktop` or `kde-plasma-desktop` (adds 300megs to xfce) or maybe just the desktop stuff from `plasma-desktop` (still 200megs to xfce). Or for others there's `xubuntu-desktop` (or just `xfce4`), `lubuntu-desktop` (or just `lxde`), `mate-desktop`, Installing those with `apt-get` or synaptic or regular Software... should work.

Comment: so... I need to purge kde-full, then install kubuntu-desktop, then install kde-plasma-desktop?

Comment: If you can still boot into another desktop (like regular Ubuntu/Unity) or to a terminal then purging kde should leave you with a "fresh slate" to try installing it again (maybe not best answer, doesn't "fix", but it should work). I don't know which package you used to install KDE though, should show up in Synaptic or the Software center? I didn't see the difference between kubuntu-desktop and kde-plasma-desktop, but there are some old packages that have been replaced, but still show up -- But if your install is so new, it might be easier & faster to reinstall a fav desktop from iso/usb/cd/dvd

Comment: Solved! I'm one step closer to create my perfect virtual world. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. And definitely give the virtual machines (like VirtualBox) a try for test-driving new desktops, there's an insane amount of them -- like if someone told me they were going to make a new desktop, only 22+ of them, all pretty similar, I'd question their sanity ;-) lol